# DataBinding Radio Buttons

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, radio-button, 2-way-object-databinding

I will try to keep this concise as possible.

I am having an issue where I have a two way databinding  with 3 radio buttons. My issue is, I am getting sort of a cyclical change as soon as I change the chosen radio button. So what is happening, I change the radio button which changes the source data property, but the source data property changes the other 2 properties that are bound, which in turn changes the other radio buttons, which calls the PropertyChange function on those properties as well. How can I fix it so that the PropertyChange only happens once per radio button switch.

Property Changed Event Handler:

```
public class SolutionOptions : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool _direct;
    bool _iterative;
    bool _domain;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public bool Domain
    {
        get { return _domain; }
        set
        {
            if (_domain == value) return;

            _domain = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Domain");
        }
    }

    public bool Iterative
    {
        get { return _iterative; }
        set
        {
            if (_iterative == value) return;

            _iterative = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Iterative");
        }
    }

    public bool Direct
    {
        get { return _direct; }
        set
        {
            if (_direct == value) return;

            _direct = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Direct");
        }
    }
```

Data Binding Code:

```
 this.radioButton_DirectSolver.DataBindings.Add("Checked", _ssf, "SolOptions.Direct");
 this.radioButton_IterSolver.DataBindings.Add("Checked", _ssf, "SolOptions.Iterative");
 this.radioButton_DomainDecomp.DataBindings.Add("Checked", _ssf, "SolOptions.Domain");
```

Form Image:

[image]

Comment: You do know you only have 1 get? You need 3.

Comment: @Blam Oops, I omitted the gets to reduce the code. Seems like I missed one.

Comment: Don't reduce code that is a central part to the question.  Without that the binding would fail and the question is about binding.

Comment: You should not have cycling going on.  Something strange is happening.  Try  binding in XAML and posting that.

Comment: I do not know how to do the binding in XAML. I do not have an XAML to bind it with.

Comment: OK sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

First try adding this to all your setters

```
if (_domain == value) return;
```

So you don't call OnPropertyChanged if it does not change.
This is a good practice in general.

Second (only if the first does not work) put each button in a separate group so they don't call each other and handle setting others to false in your code behind.

Comment: Each radio button? Or the radio button group?

Comment: Did you try the first?  Only try the second if the first does not work.  On the second each button is in a separate group (so they are not in the same group).

Comment: I found out that the radio buttons weren't actually in the group box. However, now the radio buttons won't switch properly, and is causing other issues. I think I might just implement the radio button updates manually.